# Dynamically bound variable : revert to previous state

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to understand dynamical and lexical bindings of a variable.
I was browsing SO and some links, when I encountered a problem on this one :
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding#toc2

I ran this code :

```
(let ((a 1))
  (let ((f (lambda () (print a))))
    (let ((a 2))
      (funcall f))))
```

With expected result : `1` (and a warning which says that the second `a` variable is unused, which is normal).

Next, I tried :

```
(defvar a 99)
```

And reran the first code. Result is 2, like the tutorial says. Then, to experiment further, I tried to remove the dynamically binding variable `a`, to get again `1`.

I tried to `(makunbound 'a)` or even `(setq a 55)` (I tried this by default, I think global lexical binding depends on implementation if I understand correctly...). `makunbound` seems to remove the symbol, but the "dynamically binding state" seems to be saved anyway. The result is still `2`.

How can I reset Common Lisp to the previous state (before I dynamically bind the `a` variable) ? Restart SLIME do the trick, but I would rather have a way to do it programatically...

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The problem is that `a` is declared special. I think it's not possible to undo  that. Thus it's best not to use variable names like `a`, but to follow the convention to name special variables `*a*`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the term `special variable`. I did read about the `*variable-name*` convention, and I understand it better if removing the special declaration is impossible.

Comment: Common Lisp may call them *dynamic variable*, which are declared by DEFVAR, DEFPARAMETER, special declarations, ...  http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm#defvar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *portable* way to revert the
[`special`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_specia.htm)
[`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm)ation.
([CLISP](http://clisp.org) offers
[`notspecial`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/declarations.html#notspec-decl)).

However, you can use [`unintern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm)
to some extent: it will make *new* code treat your symbol as not
`special` because it is now a *different* symbol:

```
(defun test-a ()
  (let ((a 1))
    (let ((f (lambda () (print a))))
      (let ((a 2))
        (funcall f)))))
(test-a)
==> 1
(defvar a)
(test-a)
==> 2
```

now, let us try to "revert" [`defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm):

```
(unintern 'a)
(test-a)
==> 2
```

oops! Let us see:

```
(fdefinition 'test-a)
#<FUNCTION TEST-A NIL (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN TEST-A))
  (BLOCK TEST-A
   (LET ((#:A 1)) (LET ((F (LAMBDA NIL (PRINT #:A)))) (LET ((#:A 2)) (FUNCALL F)))))>
```

you see, `test-a` is still using the old symbol `a` which is now uninterned (so printed as `#:A`).  To get back, you need to re-[`eval`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eval.htm) the [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) above and then you get

```
(test-a)
==> 1
```

again!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the function was saving the old symbol.